# Not able to properly obtain selected checkboxes through javascript

Tags: javascript, jstl

I have a jsp page where there are certain number of checkboxes that are dynamically generated.

Here is a snippet of the code from the jsp page:

```
      <form>
            <br>
            <table align="center" border="1">
            <tr><th>Employee ID</th><th>SkillSet</th><th>Experience</th><th>Assign</th></tr>
            <c:forEach var="bean" items="${rteorbalssn}">
            <tr>
                <td><a id="${bean.pbeanempid}" onclick="funcredi(this.id)" href="#">${bean.pbeanempid}</a></td>
                <td>${bean.pbeanskill}</td>
                <td>${bean.pbeanexp}</td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" id="${bean.pbeanempid}" name="assignment" ></td>
            </tr>
            </c:forEach>
            </table>
              <br><table align="center"><tr><td align="center"><input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="func(this.value,${rteorbalssn[0].clickcode})"/></td></tr>
            </table>
      </form>
```

And my javascript:

```
function func(clicked,projcode)
{
    if(clicked == 'Submit')
    {

        var count=0;
        var selected=[];
        for(var i=0; i < document.forms[0].assignment.length; i++){
            if(document.forms[0].assignment[i].checked)
                    {
                        selected.push(document.forms[0].assignment[i].id);
                        count++;
                    }
        }
        if(selected.length==0)
            alert("Atleast 1 employee must be assigned before submission!") 
        else 
        {
            alert("No of employees selected: "+count);
            selected.push(projcode);
            window.open("http://localhost:9090/HCLRMS/empasub?users="+selected,"_self");

        }
    }
}
```

### Case : 1

Suppose there are 3 rows generated :

```
    Employee ID  SkillSet  Experience  Assign 
-----------------------------------------------
    056415        JAVA,C        4         ❏ 
    545646        JAVA          1         ❏  
    387999        JAVA          6         ❏
```

If 1 or more checkboxes is/are selected,the javascript shows the following alert:
No of employees selected: <1 or 2 or 3 as per the no.of selections>

OR

If no checkbox is selected,the javascript shows the following alert:
Atleast 1 employee must be assigned before submission!
(i.e it works perfectly)

### Case : 2

Suppose there is 1 row generated :

```
    Employee ID  SkillSet  Experience  Assign 
----------------------------------------------
    056415        JAVA,C        4         ❏
```

If the checkbox is selected or is not selected,the javascript shows the following alert:
Atleast 1 employee must be assigned before submission!

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not believe there is any property called "assignments" on a form by default. What you want to be using is something on the lines of

```
var inputs = document.forms[0].getElementsByTagName("input")

    for (var i=0; i<inputs.length; i++) {

        if (inputs[i].type === "checkbox" && inputs[i].checked){
            // do your thing
        }

    }
```

Comment: That did work!
+1 to that!

But "assignment" is just the name given to the group of text boxes and is not a property.
It worked for the rest of the cases but why not for the particular case? (Case: 2) ?
My question lies there!

Comment: Sorry, I did not see the name property. You want to use document.forms[0].elements.assignment